# Rails 4 unpermitted parameter using fields_for ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

**view:**

```
<%= fields_for :contact do |field| %>
  <%= field.label :contact, 'First Name' %><br>
  <%= field.text_field :first_name %><br>

  <%= field.label :contact, 'Last Name' %><br>
  <%= field.text_field :last_name %><br>
<% end %>
```

**log:**

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"9BpMx004nc+JW0RQec8T7E1sthvSPxxC9l/4Waq7jpY=",
>   "user"=>{"contact"=>{"first_name"=>"Joe", "last_name"=>"Guy"}, ...
>
> Unpermitted parameters: contact

So I did this in my: **controller:**

```
params.require(:user).permit(contact: [:first_name, :last_name], ... )
```

Now I get a syntax error:

> syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...).permit

**objective:**

I have a `contact:text` field in my database. I want to store data in this field as an array. Such as `first_name` and `last_name` etc. Using `fields_for` to build the form. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `contact: [:first_name, :last_name]` without hash brackets `{}` if the hash elements are the last in the method call. But if you want it to occur first, try this:

```
params.require(:user).permit({ contact: [:first_name, :last_name] }, ... )
```